# Functions product by limit of one function

Tags: calculus, limits

I've read the following claim, and wander how to prove or disprove it:

For a given function $f(z)=g(z)\cdot h(z)$ so that $\lim_{z\to0}g(z)=a$,

there is $h(z)$ so that $f(z)=g(z)\cdot [a+h(z)]$

and $\lim_{z\to0}h(z)=0$

Can someone explain that?

Comment: I think your question is confused.  Please be careful with which function is $g$ and which is $h$.  I suspect what you mean is,
if $\lim_{z \to 0} g(z) = a$, then you can write $g(z) = a + r(z)$ with $\lim_{z \to 0} r(z) = 0$, and $g(z) h(z) = (a + r(z)) h(z)$.

Comment: My question is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then this statement is false:
$$\lim_{z\to 0}g(z)=a$$
$$\lim_{z\to 0}h(z)=0$$
Which means
$$\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}g(z)\lim_{z\to 0}h(z)=0\neq \lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}g(z)\lim_{z\to 0}[a+h(z)]=a^2$$

Comment: Robert comment is true. My question was confused.
Sorry for that.

Comment: One more uncertainty: is the question about proving/disproving $f(z)=g(z)h(z)=(a+r(z))h(z)$ or $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}g(z)h(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}(a+r(z))h(z)$ ?